# JavaScript: Function not returning largest prime factor

Tags: javascript, loops, primes, prime-factoring

Input: **13195**
Expected Result: **29** (largest prime factor of input)
Actual Result: **2639** (largest factor of input, but not a prime number)

I didn't bother with even numbers because the largest prime will either be 2 or some odd prime multiplied by 2 to get the input, so what's the point.

```
function findPrimeFactor(num) {

    let prime;

    for (let factor = 3; factor < num; factor += 2) {
        if (num % factor === 0) {
            for (let i = 3; i < factor; i += 2) {
                if (factor % i === 0) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    prime = factor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem of your code is in the else block. Where every time the program flow enters that block, you replace the `prime` value with `factor` value. The answer is to adding an extra temporary variable and in the else block, replacing the value of that.
I did it for you in below code:

```
function findPrimeFactor(num) {

let prime;
let temp = 3;    // Default value for numbers those their largest prime factor is 3
for (let factor = 3; factor < num; factor += 2) {
    if (num % factor === 0) {
        for (let i = 3; i < factor; i += 2) {
            if (factor % i === 0) {
            temp = prime;  // This value is not prime, so we should not replace the value of prime variable with it.
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp = factor; // This factor could be prime. We save it in the temp. If the for loop never meets the upper if block, so this is prime and we can have it.
            }
        }
        prime = temp; // temp value now is a prime number. so we save it to prime variable
    }
}
return prime;
}
```

I just corrected your code behavior and don't add extra behavior to it.
Hope this helped you.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. So if the factor is **203**, a non-prime number, when it first enters the nested loop and does the check: **203 % 3 != 0**, so that automatically puts it in the else block *(in my function)*?

Comment: Yes, that is. I corrected it for you in the above code.

Comment: this doesn't work for a lot of number btw. it returns undefined plenty of times. (try with 27, it returns undefined instead of 3)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer for numbers those their largest prime factor is 3. But the function still returns undefined for prime numbers. The reason I did not correct that is the questioner didn't want that.

Answer (score 0):

for reference [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-largest-prime-factor-number/), there was other languages, I done the js one

```
function findPrimeFactor(num) {
    // Initialize the maximum prime factor
    // variable with the lowest one
    let prime = -1;

    // Print the number of 2s
    // that divide n
    while (num % 2 === 0) {
        prime = 2;
        num = num / 2;
    }

    // n must be odd at this point,
    // thus skip the even numbers
    // and iterate only for odd
    // integers       
    for (let factor = 3; factor <= Math.sqrt(num); factor += 2) {
        while (num % factor === 0) {
            prime = factor;
            num = num / factor;
        }
    }

    // This condition is to handle
    // the case when n is a prime
    // number greater than 2
    if (num>2)
       prime = num;

    return prime;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link earlier when I was researching this. But what I'm wondering is why I'd need to divide num back into the factor for that while loop.

Comment: which one while loop? the second one?

Comment: Yeah, the while loop nested within the for loop that iterates over odd integers

Comment: Because if you find that a number might be divided by "3" for example, you need to check how many times it can be divided by 3 :) 

Like -> 27 -> you find that it can be divided by 3 -> 27/3 = 9 -> 9 can be divided by 3 again? yes, so 9 / 3 = 3, 3 can be divided by 3? yes and so on...