# Ruby: Program I wrote in JavaScript not working the same way in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, primes, prime-factoring

I initially wrote this in JavaScript, and posted here asking for help (which I got). I then wrote it in Ruby, and it's not working as intended. It looks like the code is pretty much the same in Ruby.

Expected result: **29**
Actual result: **2639**

```
prime = 0
temp = 0
factor = 3
i = 3
num = 13195

while factor < num
    if num % factor == 0
        while i < factor
            if factor % i == 0
                temp = prime
                break
            else
                temp = factor
            end
            i = i + 2
        end
        // i initializes back to 3 
        // so next factor can properly iterate through loop
        i = 3 
        prime = temp
    end
    factor = factor + 2
end
i = 3
puts prime
```

And here's the link to the answer when I asked this as a JavaScript program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970934/7217977

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yeah, why am I not getting the expected result?

Comment: Have you tried debugging both programs step by step and trying to find where their outputs start to diverge?

Comment: Hint: your translation of c-style `for` loops has one small flaw.

Comment: Another user told me i never resets to 3, it value just increases. So when the next factor goes through the loop, it doesn't do factor % 3...and so on, but rather factor % (i + 2). I think I fixed that, check out the edit to my code above, now I get the expected result, but not sure if that's still the proper solution.

Comment: "not sure if that's still the proper solution" - if it works, it's "good enough". But this is not very idiomatic ruby, indeed. Not idiomatic at all. Max gives good advice about ruby loops, you should use that instead (for future code).

Comment: Ruby is still really brand new to me, so I'm only writing syntax that I understand even if it's not the best. My future code will be better as I get more comfortable with the language.

Comment: Yep. Simply read a lot of [good] code and write a lot of code, and you'll be a ruby master in no time. Like, a year or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, `for (let i = 3; i < factor; i += 2)` initializes `i` to 3 and then loops. But in your Ruby code you are initializing `i` only once at the very beginning, then each of your loops is reusing that one value of `i` without resetting it back to 3.

The Ruby way of translating that for loop is like this

```
(3...factor).step(2) do |i|
  # loop code
end
```

this creates a block-local `i` that is reset for every iteration of the loop and cannot be interfered with by outer scopes.

Comment: I think I might have found a fix to that, I set i back to 3 just before the outer while loop ends, and I get the expected result. I edited my code and added a comment about doing that above.